# Run KitKat Virtual Device on Intel CPU

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, android-4.4-kitkat

When creating a new Virtual Device in AVD, if I select a target of API 18, I see a drop down to choose the CPU (I choose Intel). If I select the API Level 19, the CPU dropdown is disabled and stuck to ARM.

Is it simply because the Intel simulator is not yet released for API 19? Or am I missing some configuration somewhere?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Intel releases their own image most of the time a few weeks later.
Check for updates periodically with the SDK manager, and if it's there, download it and then you can use it.